# Константная rvalue ссылка

Tags: c++

```
const Type &&
```

Используется ли где-то константная rvalue ссылка?

Comment: Кто-то на ruSO как-то говорил, что да... Но не помню, кто и где именно :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С точки зрения функциональности `const Type &&` не предоставляет вам ничего свыше того, что предоставляет `const Type &`. Поэтому из соображений того, что "`const Type &` был первым", смысла в `const Type &&` нет.

Overload resolution позволяет различать `const Type &` и `const Type &&`, то есть существует возможность написать перегруженные функции с такими параметрами и затем выбирать одну из них в точке вызова. В рамках этого замечания приходит в голову только что, что вы по какой-то причине можете хотеть иметь функцию с `const Type &` параметром, но при этом можете захотеть потребовать, чтобы этот параметр привязывался только к "реальным" объектам (то есть к lvalue-выражениям), но не к временным объектам. В такой ситуации можно сделать перегрузку для `const Type &&` и объявить ее как deleted

```
void foo(const int &) {}
void foo(const int &&) = delete;

int main()
{
  int i = 42;
  foo(i);  // OK
  foo(42); // Error
}
```